# How to configure Hibernate Statement Inspector per session at runtime with AOP?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-aop

I am looking at the documentation [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/resource/jdbc/spi/StatementInspector.html) for StatementInspector.

The documentation states the following:

> A StatementInspector may be either:
>
> - shared by all sessions created by a given session factory, in which case it must be thread-safe, or
> - a dedicated instance registered for a certain session.

Well, I am interested in a dedicated instance registered for a certain session.
I am currently able to apply a statementInspector for a given session with the following code:

MyRepository.java

```
Session originalSession = em.unwrap(Session.class);
SQLStatementInspector sqlStatementInspector = new SQLStatementInspector();
SessionBuilder sessionBuilder = originalSession.sessionWithOptions().statementInspector(sqlStatementInspector);
Session newSessionWithStatementInspector = sessionBuilder.openSession();

CriteriaBuilder builder = newSessionWithStatementInspector.getCriteriaBuilder();
...
newSessionWithStatementInspector.createQuery(builder.createQuery()).getResultList();
```

The above code works, but I would prefer not to modify the session object in every repository method / call.

Ideally, I would like to enable the statement inspector for only certain API calls or for certain Repository Method calls. I have tried to abstract out the code into an Aspect, but it does not work.

Does anyone know a better way to enrich the Thread Local Session with a statement inspector at runtime?

This is Aspect code that I tried:

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class StatementInspectorAspect {

    @Autowired
    private EntityManager em;

    @Before("execution(* com.ea.MyRepository.findAll(..)) && args(appointmentId, type, sortKey, sortDirection)")
    public void before(JoinPoint joinPoint, Long appointmentId, String type, String sortKey, String sortDirection) {

        Session unwrap = em.unwrap(Session.class);
        SQLStatementInspector sqlStatementInspector = new SQLStatementInspector();
        SessionBuilder sessionBuilder = unwrap.sessionWithOptions().statementInspector(sqlStatementInspector);
        final Session session2 = sessionBuilder.openSession();
        this.em = session2;
    }
}
```